# fbt internationalization: ERROR in ./src/example/Example.react.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fbt'

Tags: reactjs, facebook, internationalization

I try to use new internationalization library from facebook - fbt, I follow by steps in doc:

```
git clone git@github.com:facebookincubator/fbt.git;
cd fbt/demo-app;
yarn install; # pull in dependencies
yarn manifest; # generate fbt enum manifests and source manifests
yarn collect-fbts; # Collect all fbt phrases from source
yarn translate-fbts; # Generate the translation payloads
yarn build;
yarn start; # Checkout your locally running server at localhost:8081
```

And in next I got next error on yarn build step:

```
ERROR in ./src/example/Example.react.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fbt' in '/home/test/projects/fbt/demo-app/src/example'
 @ ./src/example/Example.react.js 36:0-80 37:0-4 100:17-31 104:18-29 113:6-23 141:9-12 143:43-46 145:43-46 159:10-27 164:15-29 165:9-12 168:15-29 169:9-12 172:15-29 173:9-12 176:15-29 177:9-12 185:21-24 198:21-24 219:15-29 220:9-12 223:15-29 224:9-12 227:15-29 228:9-12 231:15-29 232:9-12 236:9-12 238:10-13 240:58-61 243:9-12 246:10-13 256:21-24 289:15-26 290:9-12 293:15-26 294:9-12 297:15-26 298:9-12 301:15-26 302:9-12 305:15-26 306:9-12 309:15-26 310:9-12 314:9-12 340:10-13 344:32-35 344:78-81 346:9-12 346:27-30 348:9-12 352:12-15 362:9-12
 @ ./src/root.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies!  It looks like we were missing a step in our documentation!  You'll need to run `yarn` in the top-level first (to build the runtime library):

```
git clone git@github.com:facebookincubator/fbt.git;
cd fbt;
yarn;
cd demo-app
yarn ...
```